# How to know remaining balance for Azure subscription? (Remaining = Credits - Usage)

Tags: azure-billing-api

I am able to consume the Azure REST APIs - RateCard & Usage.

Using combination of above APIs, I am able to calculate the cost of Consumption(usage).

To find the Credits, it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43025432/1699234),

> first, you would need to find the total credits available. This information can be fetched via Rate Card API. This will be available under OfferTerms element in the response.

but I received below response in RateCard API:

```
 "OfferTerms": [
    {
        "ExcludedMeterIds": [],
        "Name": "Monetary Credit"
    }
],
```

Hence, my question is How can I find the credit transactions for the subscription in order to calculate the remaining balance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the scenario as per the documentation available [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api)
(I'd recommend checking it)The script does still include the bellow info:

```
<add key="ADALRedirectURL" value="https://localhost/"/>
<add key="TenantDomain" value="ENTER.AAD.TENANT.DNS.NAME"/>                           
<add key="SubscriptionID" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>
<add key="ClientId" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>
```

Have you double checked if all the IDs above were correct ?

Comment: Yes, all the values are correct and I am able to successfully consume those two APIs viz., Usage and RateCard. As mentioned in question, in order to calculate the remaining credit, I need to subtract the usage(which I calculated already with combination of Usage & RateCard) from total credit. The problem is I am not able to find the **Credit** transactions for subscriptions i.e. total credits done so far.

Comment: I see, have you checked this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-balance-summary , although it is monthly, you could start using the first month's data,record the remaining value then substract or add credit on whatever variable to track it in the future.

Comment: I checked it, but AFAIK it seems related to Enterprise Customer, whereas we are not. What I want to achieve **through API** is what we can already see using _portal.azure.com > Subscriptions > Cost Management + Billing > Credit History_.